# How does a COM client parses Type Library from a EXE COM server?

Tags: windows, com, internals, idl, typelib

Let's say we have a COM server EXE and COM client EXE running on the same machine.

COM server exposes IDispatch interface and carries a Type Library (.TLB file) into it's resource section.

COM client (something like PowerShell) wants to call a method and it does so via IDispatch::Invoke.

Before Client could make that call, If I understood it correctly, it must read Type Library of the COM class which can be done via the [LoadTypeLib](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oleauto/nf-oleauto-loadtypelib) function

It's easy to digest if it were to be a COM server DLL, where client-server would be living in the same address space.

But what happens when the COM server is an EXE? Does the Client (which itself is an EXE) loads the server EXE (Not sure if that is even possible) ?

Remarks on MSDN has this

> If the file is a DLL or an executable file, it is loaded. By default,
> the type library is extracted from the first resource of type
> ITypeLib.

Comment: The type library is usually stored in the registry I think.  The client can look it up by UUID if I recall.

Comment: A type library is a blob in a format that LoadTypeLib understands. It can be stored in a .dll or .exe as a Win32 embedded resource or stored as an external file (usually with the .tlb extension). It's usually also registered by it's id (the TLBID, a GUID) in the registry in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib and the registry points to the .dll, .exe or external file.

Comment: So does the client needs to "Load" the EXE into its address space (so that it can read the type lib from it's resource) ? or it remains transperant to the Client and when LoadTypeLib returns it has all the info it needs and Windows does the heavy lifting of reading the Server EXE from the disk and parsing the type lib from it's resource?

Comment: No, since this part of the registry is accessible to all processes, once a process has a TLBID, it can determine from the registry what file holds the the TLB blob and read it using LoadTypeLib.

Comment: The type library is entirely unnecessary for making `IDispatch` calls. One does not need to call `LoadTypeLib` in order to be able to call through `IDispatch`. There are other reasons to want to consult the type library, but this is not one of them.

Comment: But yes, if you do call `LoadTypeLib` passing the path of an EXE or DLL file, that file is mapped into your process' memory in order to extract a resource from it.